# Error with my login servlet

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a login servlet using glassfish server and no matter what i have keyed in(correct information or wrong information) always get me back to the index page instead of test page.

here are the codes for my servlet

```
package com.java.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.*
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@WebServlet("/validate")
public class ValidationServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource(name="Project")
    private DataSource dsProject1;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Get the input from the request
        String strEmail = req.getParameter("email");
        String strPassword = req.getParameter("password");
        String strMemberId = "";

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        boolean loginSuccess = false;

        try
        {
            conn = dsProject1.getConnection();

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = strEmail AND password = md5(strPassword)";

            statement = conn.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            if(loginSuccess = rs.next())
            {      
                strMemberID = rs.getString("memberid");
            }


        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }        
        finally
        {
            if(rs != null)
            {                    
                try
                {
                    rs.close();
                }
                catch (SQLException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }


            if(statement != null)
            {

                try
                {
                    statement.close();
                }
                catch (SQLException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                }


            }

            if(conn != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.close();
                }
                catch (SQLException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                }

            }

        }

        if (loginSuccess == true) {


            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("memberId", strMemberID);

            RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp");
            rd.forward(req, res);
        } else {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("error", "Your email or password is incorrect!");
            RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            rd.forward(req, res);

        }


    }
}


is there anything wrong with my sql statement or my codes?
thanks a million! :*
```

Comment: `if(loginSuccess = rs.next())` - Typo during copy or in actual code?

Comment: that's in my actual code :3 what can i change it to?

Comment: If you are testing for equality you need to use `==` or `Equals()`  as you have later in your code.

Comment: @shree.pat18 I think you're missing the obvious.

Comment: That's entirely possible since the equality check caught my eye but I did not look at the other code. That is also why I chose to comment rather than answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrong, you are always hashing the string `strPassword`:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = strEmail AND password = md5(strPassword)";
```

You are not substituting the variable from the client. You need to use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = strEmail AND password = md5(?)");
ps.setString(1, strPassword);
```

Now onto the next issue:

```
if (loginSuccess = rs.next()) {
    strMemberID = rs.getString("memberid");
}
```

This says assign `rs.next()` to `loginSuccess`. `=` is the *assignment operator* and `==` is equality operator. This statement always returns `true`.

So this should be:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    strMemberID = rs.getString("memberid");
}
```

Also, use Java 7 try-with-resources rather than `try..finally`. This will really tidy your code:

```
try (final Connection conn = dsProject1.getConnection()) {
    final String sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = strEmail AND password = md5(?)";
    try (final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setString(1, strPassword);
        try (final ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                loginSuccess = true;
                strMemberID = rs.getString("memberid");
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Finally, nip that strange habit of assigning all your variables to `null` first then reassigning them in the bud **right now**. There is never a reason to do this, it leads to ugly and illegible code and also to bugs.

Comment: but i did declare 
String strPassword = req.getParameter("password");
is it still wrong?

Comment: Declaring a variable doesn't magically make it substitute itself into a `String`. How would that even work??

Comment: i've tried changing those and it still can't work.. :\ could it be problem with my database?

Comment: Debug your servlet, work out what the various variables are. Build the query manually, run it against the DB to see what happens.

Comment: if i were to remove the if(login = rs.next()) , my whole program wont work, why is it so?

Comment: @user3774763 if you remove that, then the `ResultSet` will not be advanced. But this statement **always** sets `login` to `true` regardless of the return of `next()` because `=` is _assignment_. You need to rethink your logic.